# Changing R studio appearance to default

Tags: rstudio

Recently, I changed the appearance of my R studio to Xcode. I liked its text color on the scripts part but didn't like the color on the console. It doesn't have a different color option for error and warning messages. So, I want to go back to the default one, whatever the R Studio comes with. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

The default RStudio theme is 'Modern' the default editor theme is TextMate.

Answer (score 2):

To change the Editor theme to default you must go to Tools -> Global Options -> Appearance. Then, in the Editor theme section you have to select TextMate(defauilt) which is the default editor theme you have when you install RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the appearance you can do this by going to Tools -> Global Options -> Appearance. There are several options for the Rstudio theme and the editor.

The [RStudio Support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011846747-Using-RStudio-Themes) describes this in greater depth.